# Appending in an empty list all the values of a dict key

Tags: python, dictionary, coordinates, networkx

I'm currently working with graphs (with python module networkx) and my task is to make two different sets one for all the longitude values of the nodes and one for all the latitude values. When I read through the data of each node the coordinates comes in dict form, like `{lat: 1234, lon: 5678}`.

This is my code, if I print the `node_id` I get all the nodes, if I print `node_data` I get the dictionary with the values of the coordinates:

```
all_nodes = G.node
for node in all_nodes:
  node_id = node
  node_data = G.node[node_id]
```

Re-edit: As it wasn't that clear, at the bottom of the above code there are two print statement:

```
 all_nodes = G.node
 for node in all_nodes:
  node_id = node
  node_data = G.node[node_id]
  print: "Node Id :", node_id
  print: "Coordinates:", node_data
```

This gives me as output all the nodes id and all the coordinates. As I asked I would like to know how to get in two different sets lat and long.

Comment: Where's your code ? What have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: I've tried iteritems, and both of the answers provided below, but the best I could get are only two values and not all of them. I've edited the questions and I put my lines of code to get all the coordinates.

Comment: Err... Ok, given the code you posted, I suggest you __first__ learn Python. At least the basic stuff, like how python's `for` loop work, what `dict` and `list` are etc.

Comment: It's clearly missing the last part. At the end of the loop there were two print statements that showed the content of node_id and node_data. but I need, instead of that, to get separately latitude and longitude. I don't really know how to explain it differently. And thank for the sarcasm btw, I really deserve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in this way, even though I've extracted the coordinates I've found in the list of edges and not in the nodes data:

```
out_edges = G.out_edges(G, data= True)

for edge in out_edges:

    lat = []
    lon = []
    x = edge[0]
    y = edge[1]
    lat.append(x)
    lon.append(y)
    print lat
    print lon
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly, this should do the trick:

```
 lat = [node['lat'] for node in nodes]
```

Comment: This is working, but looks like I get only two values of the whole set.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d['lat'], d['long'] = [], []
>>> d
{'lat': [], 'long': []}
```

Now you can append the lattitude and longitude in a list,and can simply extract it.

Comment: This raise an error: list indices must be integers, not str.

Comment: what you are doing show the code?, because this is running for me.